# do basic lands count against sideboard total?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

http://www.starcitygames.com/magic/legacy/21524_The_Long_And_Winding_Road_Legacy_Elves.html

All the spells in that deck are green as are all the creatures. And yet the deck has two fetch lands - Misty Rainforests - which fetches islands and forests - and Verdant Catacombs - which fetches forests and swamps.

Some of the cards in the sideboard are blue and black I note. My guess: basic lands can be swapped out without needing to live in your sideboard?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot swap in basic lands during a match or tournament in constructed unless they are part of your sideboard.

The fetch lands are in the deck to filter the lands as soon as possible. They only fetch forests in this deck. When you fetch a forest, there are less cards in your deck, so the chance of drawing a card you want (not a land usually) is bigger.

The black and blue cards in the sideboard are traps, they can be played for free in certain circumstances, so therefore you need no black or blue mana.

Comment: The traps would also be playable with birchlore rangers.

Comment: Deck thinning via fetchlands provides only marginal benefit; they're more useful for a free shuffle effect and/or color correction, or additional landfall triggers. I don't see a need for either shuffling or color correction, and I see no landfall. Honestly, I wouldn't include fetchlands in this deck.

Comment: Re "You cannot swap basic lands during a match or tournament in constructed", Could you back up this claim? I don't see anything in the CR or TR saying you can't put basic lands in your sideboard or anything preventing you from swapping them in. In the mean time, I've edited your post in the event that you simply misspoke.

Comment: @BrianS They're in this deck because it's a combo deck that relies on drawing a lot of cards one at a time. Thinning 1 or 2 lands is a huge deal when you start with 14 lands and then try to draw your deck.